# md5sum check fails for git-man-pages.tar.gz package

Tags: git, hashsum, github, integrity

When I try to verify the integrity of git-man-pages package I downloaded from "http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz&can=2&q=" it fails with error.

**Command which i ran:** `md5sum -c git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz`

**Error displayed:**

```
md5sum: git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
```

I also tried entering the checksum value of git-manpages that i found in site in a file called checksum in the following format

```
8c67a7bc442d6191bc17633c7f2846c71bda71cf  git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz
```

and then running the

**Command:** `md5sum -c checksum`

**Error displayed:**

```
md5sum: checksum: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to compute the checksum of the file you downloaded you should leave the `-c` out. Apologies if I didn't understand your question right. For example:

```
$ md5sum git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz 
e3720f56e18a5ab8ee1871ac9c72ca7c  git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz
```

md5sum also expects 2 spaces between checksum and file name in files to be used with `-c`, just like in the output above.

Comment: The command md5sum git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz gives the same checksum.. But that differs from the checksum given in the download link from where i downloaded the package (http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/detail?name=git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz&can=2&q=).. We're not supposed to compare the one in the site and the one we got? Just md5sum package-name and if it returns some random checksum, our package integrity is good? Please clarify.. Thanks.

Comment: The checksum calculated by `md5sum` is always the same, so if it differs from the one listed on the download page that information is either outdated or the file you downloaded is corrupt. If it is actually corrupt it won't unpack properly anyways though.

Comment: I guess, outdated then.. Because it unpacked without any error.. and works good, as well..

Comment: My bad.. It's SHA1 checksum and hence i need to use sha1sum command.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

At the bottom of that page, there is sha256sums.txt, which contains the hashes of each file in that directory. You can verify using:

```
sha256sum ./git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz
```

or you can verify the PGP signature provided with the release. Download git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.sign, and do the following:

```
gunzip -cd git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.gz | gpg --verify git-manpages-1.8.4.tar.sign -
```

See this page for more detailed instructions: https://www.kernel.org/signature.html